# In an extreme hills biome, at what level does snow appear?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When traveling through an extreme hills biome, how high do you have to go for snow to appear?

Answer (score 2):

***95***

Extreme Hills generate snow at a height (Y axis) of 95.

The math for that is simple:

- It has a base temp of 0.2 at sea level and below (highland biome)
- Snow requires it to be *less than 0.15*
- Temps drop by 1/600 per meter
- you need a drop of more than 0.05 degrees
- 1/600 * 30 = 0.05 (because 600 * 0.05 = 30)
- 30 blocks are exactly 0.05 degrees of temp drop, so you need one more: 64 + 30 + 1 = 95

([Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Biome))